# How to make ELSE associate with farthest IF in yacc?

Tags: yacc, operator-precedence

I now know how to make ELSE associate with the nearest `IF`:

```
%nonassoc IFX
%nonassoc ELSE

| IF stmt %prec IFX
| IF stmt ELSE stmt
```

But how can I make `ELSE` associate with farthest `IF`?

I tried to switch the order of the two `%nonassoc` above,but after that if seems to be failing to recognizing any valid statement in th format of `IF stmt ELSE stmt`.

Why ?

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

(Untested) You need to force bison to generate a parser which reduces `if` statements if there is an ambiguity between multiple `if`s. According to http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/bison/bison_85.html this can be achieved if the `IF stmt` rule has a higher precedence then the `ELSE` token. So

```
%nonassoc ELSE
%nonassoc IFX

| IF stmt %prec IFX
| IF stmt ELSE stmt
```

should do the trick.